# how to improve performance of JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON object that I generated using PHP in the following format

```
[{
    "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:00",
    "curr_property": "7211",
    "curr_property_cost": "123",
    "day_property": "48",
    "day_property_cost": "281",
    "curr_solar_generating": "4958",
    "curr_solar_export": "0",
    "day_solar_generated": "33",
    "day_solar_export": "0",
    "curr_chan1": "1964",
    "curr_chan2": "4958",
    "curr_chan3": "289",
    "day_chan1": "13",
    "day_chan2": "33",
    "day_chan3": "1"
},
{
    "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:00",
    "curr_property": "7211",
    "curr_property_cost": "123",
    "day_property": "48",
    "day_property_cost": "281",
    "curr_solar_generating": "4958",
    "curr_solar_export": "0",
    "day_solar_generated": "33",
    "day_solar_export": "0",
    "curr_chan1": "1964",
    "curr_chan2": "4958",
    "curr_chan3": "289",
    "day_chan1": "13",
    "day_chan2": "33",
    "day_chan3": "1"
}]
```

Will changing the format to

```
    [{
    "timestamp": ["12\/16\/2013 0:00", "12\/16\/2013 0:00", ..........],
    "curr_property": ["7211","32432",...........],
    "day_chan3": ["1","2","3"............]
}
```

improve the performance ? Im new to JSON so please suggest me ways I can improve the speed of an application as the amount of JSON data is very large almost 40 MB and growing.

Comment: Why not making a small performance test yourself?

Comment: The way to "improve performance" is to not let it "keep growing" at the usage site. Rather, provide methods to consume the data only as required - or otherwise stream usage. With deflate compression I would expect "similar" over-the-wire sizes of both formats. (Also, use JSON numbers for .. numbers.)

Comment: my guess was that somebody must have already tried it, if no one answers I will have to do it.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, that seems like a very good idea. I will look into that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find out how to speed up an application?  Then use XDebug.  http://xdebug.com/  XDebug will tell you what parts of your code are slow.  Don't just try to guess at random what is being slow.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Lester, my application relies heavily on processing CSV to JSON data so my idea was reducing the size of the JSON data will help improve performance, but user2845740's suggestion is a very good, Thanks for informing about the tool